# Eigenvalues of the second exterior power of a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, exterior-algebra

Let $K$ be a field of characteristic zero and $V=K^n$. Let $T: V \to V$ be a linear map with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n \in K$ , not necessarily all distinct. Let $\wedge^2 V$ be the second exterior power of $V$ and $\wedge^2T: \wedge^2 V \to \wedge^2 V$ is the linear map defined as $\wedge^2T(x\wedge y)=T(x)\wedge T(y),\forall x,y\in V$ and extend it to whole of $\wedge ^2V$ linearly.

What are all the eigenvalues of $\wedge^2T$ ?

I can easily show that  all $\lambda_i\lambda_j$ s , with $i\ne j$ , are eigenvalues of $\wedge^2T$; my question is: are there any other eigenvalues ?

EDIT: I would accept an answer even if just for the $K=\mathbb C$ case

Comment: Long story short: no, there are no other eigenvalues.  This is easy to prove in the case that $T$ is diagonalizable, but I'm finding the proof in the general case a bit tricky.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: I see ... please do post a full proof as an answer when you have it ...

Comment: That being said: if you take $K = \Bbb R$ or $K = \Bbb C$, then we can extend the proof for diagonalizable operators by noting the continuous dependence of eigenvalues on matrix entries and the continuity of the exterior product.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: I'm not really sure how does it follow from density argument ... if $\lambda $ is an eigenvalue of $\wedge^2 T$,  and $\wedge^2 D_n \to \wedge^2 T$, where $D_n$ s are diagonalizable with $D_n \to T$ , do we know that there is a sequence $\{\lambda_n\}$ of eigenvalues of $\wedge^2 D_n$ such that $\lambda_n\to\lambda$ ?

Comment: Yes, we know exactly that.  If you prefer, we can make this argument using the fact that the characteristic polynomial depends continuously on matrix entries

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: I've asked this here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2928332/can-we-approximate-any-eigenvalue-of-a-matrix-via-eigenvalues-of-some-sequence-d ... would you please post a proof to that question ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that by saying that "$T$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n \in K$, not necessarily all distinct", you mean that the characteristic polynomial of $T$ splits over $K$ with roots $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n$ which might have multiplicities. Since the characteristic polynomial of $T$ splits over $K$, you can find an ordered basis $(e_1, \dots, e_n)$ of $V$ with respect to which $T$ is given by an upper triangular matrix $A$ with the $\lambda_i$'s on the diagonal. That is, we have for each $1 \leq i \leq n$

$$ Te_i = \lambda_i e_i \mod \operatorname{span} \{ e_j \}_{j < i}$$

Let me introduce some notation. Denote by $\mathcal{P}_2(n)$ the collection of subsets of size two of $\{ 1, \dots, n \}$. We can order the elements of $\mathcal{P}_2(n)$ according to the lexicographical order. Namely, if $\alpha = \{ i, j \}$ with $i < j$ and $\beta = \{ k, l \}$ with $k < l$ then
$$ \alpha < \beta \iff (i < k) \textrm{ or } (i = k \textrm{ and } j < l) $$
so for example, in $\mathcal{P}_2(3)$ we have
$$ \{ 1, 2 \} < \{ 1, 3 \} < \{ 2, 3 \}. $$
Given $\alpha \in \mathcal{P}_2(n)$ we can write $\alpha$ uniquely as $\alpha = \{ i, j \}$ with $1 \leq i < j \leq n$. Set $e_{\alpha} = e_i \wedge e_j$. Then $(e_{\alpha})_{\alpha \in \mathcal{P}_2(n)}$ is an ordered basis for $\Lambda^2(V)$. For example, for $n = 3$ we have the ordered basis
$$ (e_1 \wedge e_2, e_1 \wedge e_3, e_2 \wedge e_3). $$

Now let $\alpha \in \mathcal{P}_2(n)$ with $\alpha = \{ i, j \}$ for $i < j$. Write
$$ Te_i = \lambda_i e_i + \sum_{k < i} c_k e_k,
\\ Te_j = \lambda_j e_j + \sum_{l < j} d_l e_l. $$

Then

$$ \Lambda^2(T)(e_{\alpha}) = Te_i \wedge Te_j = \left( \lambda_i e_i + \sum_{k < i} c_k e_k \right) \wedge \left( \lambda_j e_j + \sum_{l < j} d_l e_l \right) \\
= \lambda_i \lambda_j e_i \wedge e_j + \\
 \sum_{i < l < j} \lambda_i d_l e_i \wedge e_l - \sum_{l < i} \lambda_i d_l e_l \wedge e_i +
\\ \sum_{k < i} \lambda_j c_k e_k \wedge e_j + \\
 \sum_{k < i, l < j, k < l} c_k d_l e_k \wedge e_l - \sum_{k < i, l < j, k > l} c_k d_l e_l \wedge e_k\\
= \lambda_i \lambda_j e_i \wedge e_j \mod \operatorname{span} \{ e_{\beta} \}_{\beta < \alpha}. $$

Hence, $\Lambda^2(T)$ is represented with respect to the ordered basis $(e_{\alpha})$ by an upper triangular matrix whose diagonal elements are $\lambda_i \lambda_j$ with $i < j$. This means that the roots of the characteristic polynomial of $\Lambda^2(T)$ are precisely $\lambda_i \lambda_j$ for $i < j$ and those are the eigenvalues of $\Lambda^2(T)$.

---

**Remark**: This argument works over any field (no need to require that the characteristic of $K$ is zero) and generalizes in a straightforward way for higher exterior powers $\Lambda^k(T)$.

Comment: This is a great answer. I guess that if the characteristic polynomial of $T$ does not split over the ground field $K$, then "strange" things may happen: That is if $K=\mathbb{R}$, and $A:\mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}^k$ has two non-real eigenvalues $z,\bar z \in \mathbb C$, then $\bigwedge^2 A$ will have $|z|^2$ as a real eigenvalue.  So, in this sense, if we list all the *real*  eigenvalues of $A$, then *not* all the real  eigenvalues of $\bigwedge^2 A$ will have to "come from" multiplication of these real eigenvalues.

Comment: In other words, even if we are only interested in real eigenvalues of $\bigwedge^2 A$, we have to include possible complex factors (eigenvalues of $A$) in our search, thus leaving the real world. However, your answer implies that if we enlarge the ground field sufficiently (e.g. by taking the algebraic closure, or the splitting field of the polynomial of $A$), then we recover all the missing factors. To conclude, modulu the issue of existence of roots for $P_A$, there are no "other" eigenvalues of $\bigwedge^2 A$, which "come out of thin air". Everything has a source.